# problem with ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivy-language

I have wrote a sign up page for my app. Everything went well until i update the code with the option selection for role. I have tried to debug but still the problem persists.

main.py`

```
# main.py
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import requests

Window.size = (310, 580)

class NavBarScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.role_button = Button(text='Select Role', size_hint=(None, None), height=44)
        self.role_button.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.role_button, 'text', x))
        self.add_widget(self.role_button)

        for role in ["Farmer", "Administrator"]:
            btn = Button(text=role, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

    def signup_request(self, username, password, role):
        signup_data = {"username": username, "password": password, "role": role}
        api_url = "https://c272-2001-d08-d2-d387-2cd9-bbf2-5f29-cacf.ngrok-free.app/signup"
        response = requests.post(api_url, json=signup_data)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Successfully signed up! Token: ", response.json()["access_token"])
        else:
            print("Signup failed. Error: ", response.json()["detail"])

class Myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("start.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("signup.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("login.kv"))
        home_screen = HomeScreen(name="home")
        home_screen.add_widget(NavBarScreen())

        screen_manager.add_widget(home_screen)
        return screen_manager

    def show_role_dropdown(self, text_field):
        text_field.focus = False
        self.screen.ids.role_dropdown.open()

    def select_role(self, role):
        self.screen.ids.role_input.text = role
        self.screen.ids.role_dropdown.dismiss()

    def change_color(self, instance):
        if instance in self.root.ids.values():
            current_id = list(self.root.ids.keys())[list(self.root.ids.values()).index(instance)]
            for i in range(4):
                if f"nav_icon{i}" == current_id:
                    self.root.ids[f"nav_icon{i + 1}"].text_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
                else:
                    self.root.ids[f"nav_icon{i + 1}"].text_color = 0, 0, 0, 1

    def goto_home_screen(self):
        self.root.current = "home"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Poppins-Medium", fn_regular=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\FONT\Poppins\Poppins-Medium.ttf")
    LabelBase.register(name="Poppins-SemiBold", fn_regular=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\FONT\Poppins\Poppins-SemiBold.ttf")

    Factory.register("NavBarScreen", cls=NavBarScreen)

    # Create an instance of Myapp and run it
    app = Myapp()
    app.run()
```

signup.kv

> 

```
# signup.kv
<SignUpScreen>:
    name: "signup"
    MDScreen:
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: rgba(246, 250, 247, 255)
            Image:
                source: r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\FONT\Pytho2farmers.zip"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.75, "center_y": .15}

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "arrow-left"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
                user_font_size: "30sp"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: rgba(26, 24, 58, 255)
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                    root.manager.current = "main"

            MDLabel:
                text: "Hi!"
                font_name: "Poppins-SemiBold"
                font_size: "26sp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6,"center_y": .85}
                color: rgba(48, 62, 39, 255)

            MDLabel:
                text: "Create an account"
                font_name: "Poppins-SemiBold"
                font_size: "18sp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .79}
                color: rgba(180, 187, 114, 255)

            MDFloatLayout:
                size_hint: .7, .07
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.71}
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Username"
                    font_name: "Poppins-Medium"
                    size_hint_y: .75
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
                    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                    foreground_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                    cursor_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                    font_size: "14sp"
                    cursor_width: "2sp"
                    multiline: False

                MDFloatLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
                    size_hint_y: .03
                    md_bg_color: rgba(178, 178, 178, 255)

            MDFloatLayout:
                size_hint: .7, .07
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.6}
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Password"
                    font_name: "Poppins-Medium"
                    size_hint_y: .75
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
                    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                    foreground_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                    cursor_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                    font_size: "14sp"
                    cursor_width: "2sp"
                    multiline: False

                MDFloatLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
                    size_hint_y: .03
                    md_bg_color: rgba(178, 178, 178, 255)

            MDFloatLayout:
                size_hint: .7, .07
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.6}
                MDTextField:
                    id: role_input  # Add this ID
                    hint_text: "Role"
                    font_name: "Poppins-Medium"
                    size_hint_y: .75
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                    foreground_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                    cursor_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                    font_size: "14sp"
                    cursor_width: "2sp"
                    multiline: False
                    readonly: True
                    on_focus: if self.focus: app.show_role_dropdown(self)

                MDRaisedButton:
                    id: role_dropdown_btn
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
                    text: "Choose Role"
                    on_release: app.show_role_dropdown(role_input)

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "SIGNUP"
                size_hint: .66, .065
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y":.33}
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                font_name: "Poppins-SemiBold"
                on_release:
                    root.signup_request(username_input.text, password_input.text, role_input.text)
```

I expect the whole thing could be run but it couldnt. i tried the debugging and what it shows is

```
                'ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.')
```

and also

```
(<class 'kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException'>, ScreenManagerException('ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.'), <traceback object at 0x000001548362E048>)
```

and

```
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Assignment\main.py", line 47, in build
     screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("signup.kv"))
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Assignment\.venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 988, in add_widget
     'ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.')
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.
```

i have no idea already. I have checked with similar questions ' solutions but still the problem persists. U are my last hope to solve this T.T

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code:

```
Builder.load_file("signup.kv")
```

returns `None`, which causes the error when you try to add it to the `screen_manager`. The reason the the above code returns `None` is that the `kv` file contains a rule `<SignUpScreen>:` that defines how a `SignUpScreen` should be built. It does not actually build an instance of `SignUpScreen`. You can fix that by changing:

```
<SignUpScreen>:
```

to:

```
SignUpScreen:
```